# Angular Material's md-nav-bar is not working properly with ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I was playing with *angular material* and *ui-router*.
Here is the **[pen](http://codepen.io/vajahath_ahmed/pen/vXqxJv?editors=1010)**.


**html**:

```
<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="'browse'" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
  <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="projects.browse" name="browse">Browse</md-nav-item>
  <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="projects.settings" name="settings">Settings</md-nav-item>
</md-nav-bar>
```

The issue is, eventhough `md-selected-nav-item="'browse'"` enables the app to activate the `browse` tab by default, It is not showing the ui-router state: `projects.browse`.
But when we click the `browse` tab it shows up. Problem is the **routing functionality is not working when the page loads up.**
**js**

```
$stateProvider
  .state({
            name: "projects",
            url: "/projects",
            template: "<h4>this is project page:</h4> <ui-view></ui-view>"
  })
  .state({
            name: "projects.browse",
            url: "/browse",
            template: "<h3>Browse</h4>"
  })
  .state({
            name: "projects.settings",
            url: "/settings",
            template: "<h3>Settings</h4>"
  });
```

Obviously I'm missing something.

**[pen](http://codepen.io/vajahath_ahmed/pen/vXqxJv?editors=1010)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdNavItem) it seems that `md-nav-sref` is actived on **clicking** the tab:

[image]

Here's a work around - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/wzLqGL)

Markup

```
<div ng-cloak ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="selectedItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="projects.browse" name="browse">Browse</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="projects.settings" name="settings">Settings</md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>

    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

angular.module('MyApp')

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {

    // for handling trailing slashes
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);

    // for any unmatched url, redirect to the default.
  // NOTE: I can't adjust this value to fix this issue.
  //       setting this to "/projects/browse" may fix this issue,
  //       but I cant go with that.
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/projects");

  $stateProvider
  .state({
            name: "projects",
            url: "/projects",
      template: "<h1>this is project page:</h1> Eventhough the browse tab is selected, content of it isn't showing when the page reloads. <ui-view></ui-view>"
  })
  .state({
            name: "projects.browse",
            url: "/browse",
      template: "<h3>Browse</h4>"
  })
  .state({
            name: "projects.settings",
            url: "/settings",
      template: "<h3>Settings</h4>"
  });

})

.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $state) {
  var initTab = "browse";
  $scope.selectedItem = initTab;
  $state.go("projects." + initTab);
})
```

Comment: This only works for an initial page. If you have for example a menu with an item that links to the projects page, controller will not reload if already on that projects page when the menu item is clicked, but the tab content will be removed (and the tab will still be selected)